Android app, Chain validation failed, Response is unreliable: its validity interval is out-of-date
Getting Below error sometimes. It started coming on the compiled application and then it was automatically fixed.
Can someone please explain why we are getting this issue and how it gets solved sometimes.

2024-10-02 20:06:03.900 12410-12456 System.err              com.example.testapplication          W  javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Chain validation failed
2024-10-02 20:06:03.901 12410-12456 System.err              com.example.testapplication          W      at com.android.org.conscrypt.SSLUtils.toSSLHandshakeException(SSLUtils.java:356)
2024-10-02 20:06:03.901 12410-12456 System.err              com.example.testapplication          W      at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.convertException(ConscryptEngine.java:1134)
2024-10-02 20:06:03.901 12410-12456 System.err              com.example.testapplication          W      at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.readPlaintextData(ConscryptEngine.java:1089)
2024-10-02 20:06:03.901 12410-12456 System.err              com.example.testapplication          W      at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.unwrap(ConscryptEngine.java:876)
2024-10-02 20:06:03.901 12410-12456 System.err              com.example.testapplication          W      at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.unwrap(ConscryptEngine.java:747)
2024-10-02 20:06:03.901 12410-12456 System.err              com.example.testapplication          W      at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.unwrap(ConscryptEngine.java:712)
2024-10-02 20:06:03.901 12410-12456 System.err              com.example.testapplication          W      at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket$SSLInputStream.processDataFromSocket(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:896)
2024-10-02 20:06:03.902 12410-12456 System.err              com.example.testapplication          W      at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket$SSLInputStream.-$$Nest$mprocessDataFromSocket(Unknown Source:0)
2024-10-02 20:06:03.902 12410-12456 System.err              com.example.testapplication          W      at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket.doHandshake(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:236)
2024-10-02 20:06:03.902 12410-12456 System.err              com.example.testapplication          W      at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket.startHandshake(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:218)
2024-10-02 20:06:03.902 12410-12456 System.err              com.example.testapplication          W      at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.kt:379)
2024-10-02 20:06:03.902 12410-12456 System.err              com.example.testapplication          W      at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.establishProtocol(RealConnection.kt:337)
2024-10-02 20:06:03.902 12410-12456 System.err              com.example.testapplication          W      at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.kt:209)
2024-10-02 20:06:03.902 12410-12456 System.err              com.example.testapplication          W      at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findConnection(ExchangeFinder.kt:226)
2024-10-02 20:06:03.903 12410-12456 System.err              com.example.testapplication          W      at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findHealthyConnection(ExchangeFinder.kt:106)
2024-10-02 20:06:03.903 12410-12456 System.err              com.example.testapplication          W      at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.find(ExchangeFinder.kt:74)
2024-10-02 20:06:03.903 12410-12456 System.err              com.example.testapplication          W      at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.initExchange$okhttp(RealCall.kt:255)
2024-10-02 20:06:03.903 12410-12456 System.err              com.example.testapplication          W      at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.kt:32)
2024-10-02 20:06:03.903 12410-12456 System.err              com.example.testapplication          W      at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
2024-10-02 20:06:03.903 12410-12456 System.err              com.example.testapplication          W      at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.kt:95)
2024-10-02 20:06:03.903 12410-12456 System.err              com.example.testapplication          W      at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
2024-10-02 20:06:03.904 12410-12456 System.err              com.example.testapplication          W      at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.kt:83)
2024-10-02 20:06:03.904 12410-12456 System.err              com.example.testapplication          W      at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
2024-10-02 20:06:03.904 12410-12456 System.err              com.example.testapplication          W      at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.kt:76)
2024-10-02 20:06:03.904 12410-12456 System.err              com.example.testapplication          W      at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
2024-10-02 20:06:03.904 12410-12456 System.err              com.example.testapplication          W      at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain$okhttp(RealCall.kt:201)
2024-10-02 20:06:03.904 12410-12456 System.err              com.example.testapplication          W      at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall$AsyncCall.run(RealCall.kt:517)
2024-10-02 20:06:03.904 12410-12456 System.err              com.example.testapplication          W      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
2024-10-02 20:06:03.905 12410-12456 System.err              com.example.testapplication          W      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:644)
2024-10-02 20:06:03.905 12410-12456 System.err              com.example.testapplication          W      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
2024-10-02 20:06:03.907 12410-12456 System.err              com.example.testapplication          W  Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: Chain validation failed
2024-10-02 20:06:03.908 12410-12456 System.err              com.example.testapplication          W      at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.verifyChain(TrustManagerImpl.java:719)
2024-10-02 20:06:03.908 12410-12456 System.err              com.example.testapplication          W      at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedRecursive(TrustManagerImpl.java:549)
2024-10-02 20:06:03.908 12410-12456 System.err              com.example.testapplication          W      at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedRecursive(TrustManagerImpl.java:570)
2024-10-02 20:06:03.908 12410-12456 System.err              com.example.testapplication          W      at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedRecursive(TrustManagerImpl.java:615)
2024-10-02 20:06:03.908 12410-12456 System.err              com.example.testapplication          W      at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedRecursive(TrustManagerImpl.java:615)
2024-10-02 20:06:03.908 12410-12456 System.err              com.example.testapplication          W      at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedRecursive(TrustManagerImpl.java:615)
2024-10-02 20:06:03.909 12410-12456 System.err              com.example.testapplication          W      at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:505)
2024-10-02 20:06:03.909 12410-12456 System.err              com.example.testapplication          W      at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:425)
2024-10-02 20:06:03.909 12410-12456 System.err              com.example.testapplication          W      at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.getTrustedChainForServer(TrustManagerImpl.java:353)
2024-10-02 20:06:03.909 12410-12456 System.err              com.example.testapplication          W      at android.security.net.config.NetworkSecurityTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(NetworkSecurityTrustManager.java:94)
2024-10-02 20:06:03.909 12410-12456 System.err              com.example.testapplication          W      at android.security.net.config.RootTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(RootTrustManager.java:90)
2024-10-02 20:06:03.909 12410-12456 System.err              com.example.testapplication          W      at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket$2.checkServerTrusted(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:163)
2024-10-02 20:06:03.909 12410-12456 System.err              com.example.testapplication          W      at com.android.org.conscrypt.Platform.checkServerTrusted(Platform.java:260)
2024-10-02 20:06:03.910 12410-12456 System.err              com.example.testapplication          W      at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.verifyCertificateChain(ConscryptEngine.java:1638)
2024-10-02 20:06:03.910 12410-12456 System.err              com.example.testapplication          W      at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.ENGINE_SSL_read_direct(Native Method)
2024-10-02 20:06:03.910 12410-12456 System.err              com.example.testapplication          W      at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeSsl.readDirectByteBuffer(NativeSsl.java:570)
2024-10-02 20:06:03.910 12410-12456 System.err              com.example.testapplication          W      at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.readPlaintextDataDirect(ConscryptEngine.java:1095)
2024-10-02 20:06:03.910 12410-12456 System.err              com.example.testapplication          W      at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.readPlaintextData(ConscryptEngine.java:1079)
2024-10-02 20:06:03.910 12410-12456 System.err              com.example.testapplication          W      ... 27 more
2024-10-02 20:06:03.915 12410-12456 System.err              com.example.testapplication          W  Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Response is unreliable: its validity interval is out-of-date
2024-10-02 20:06:03.915 12410-12456 System.err              com.example.testapplication          W      at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.java:135)
2024-10-02 20:06:03.915 12410-12456 System.err              com.example.testapplication          W      at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:222)
2024-10-02 20:06:03.915 12410-12456 System.err              com.example.testapplication          W      at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:140)
2024-10-02 20:06:03.915 12410-12456 System.err              com.example.testapplication          W      at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.engineValidate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:79)
2024-10-02 20:06:03.916 12410-12456 System.err              com.example.testapplication          W      at java.security.cert.CertPathValidator.validate(CertPathValidator.java:309)
2024-10-02 20:06:03.916 12410-12456 System.err              com.example.testapplication          W      at android.sec.enterprise.certificate.DelegatingCertPathValidator.engineValidate(DelegatingCertPathValidator.java:63)
2024-10-02 20:06:03.916 12410-12456 System.err              com.example.testapplication          W      at java.security.cert.CertPathValidator.validate(CertPathValidator.java:309)
2024-10-02 20:06:03.916 12410-12456 System.err              com.example.testapplication          W      at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.verifyChain(TrustManagerImpl.java:715)
2024-10-02 20:06:03.916 12410-12456 System.err              com.example.testapplication          W      ... 44 more
2024-10-02 20:06:03.921 12410-12456 System.err              com.example.testapplication          W  Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Response is unreliable: its validity interval is out-of-date
2024-10-02 20:06:03.921 12410-12456 System.err              com.example.testapplication          W      at sun.security.provider.certpath.OCSPResponse.verify(OCSPResponse.java:619)
2024-10-02 20:06:03.922 12410-12456 System.err              com.example.testapplication          W      at sun.security.provider.certpath.RevocationChecker.checkOCSP(RevocationChecker.java:709)
2024-10-02 20:06:03.922 12410-12456 System.err              com.example.testapplication          W      at sun.security.provider.certpath.RevocationChecker.check(RevocationChecker.java:363)
2024-10-02 20:06:03.922 12410-12456 System.err              com.example.testapplication          W      at sun.security.provider.certpath.RevocationChecker.check(RevocationChecker.java:337)
2024-10-02 20:06:03.922 12410-12456 System.err              com.example.testapplication          W      at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.java:125)
2024-10-02 20:06:03.922 12410-12456 System.err              com.example.testapplication          W      ... 51 more
2024-10-02 20:06:03.922 12410-12456 API_CALL                com.example.testapplication          E  Request failed: Chain validation failed
20

